# echo the git tag used to checkout a repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML file in which I checkout a repository using git tag as follows:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo-name
    type: git
    name: name
    ref: refs/tags/2.0.2304.190
```

The pipeline sources show the tag:

[image]

Is there a way I can echo tag value "2.0.2304.190" using a YAML task?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? The "predefined variables" section, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details

```
variables:
  tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['repo'].ref ]

stages:

- stage: Build

    steps:

    - bash: |
       echo "Tag value: $(echo $TOOLS_REF | sed 's/refs\/tags\///g')"
      displayName: 'Echo tag value'
```